# Происходит ли адвербализация?

Tags: морфология

Переходит *не отвлекаясь* в разряд наречия?

> Сделав это, вы сможете **работать не отвлекаясь**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Сделав это, вы сможете работать не отвлекаясь.**

Да, деепричастие употребляется **в значении наречия, запятая не ставится**.

Однозначно отсутствует пауза после глагола "работать", ударение падет на деепричастие.

В этом случае деепричастие обозначает не второе действие, а признак действия, выраженного глаголом.